# How to make mat-label float to the right (RTL language) when input value is LTR in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have a `mat-form-field` with `appearance="outline"`.

As it's input with the type of number I want the input value to be LTR; always.

But `mat-label` is in Persian (an RTL language) so I want it to float to the right.

As you can see in the image below, right now input value is LTR and the cursor is at the left side (which is correct) but the label is also floating to the left (which is not what I want).

[image: mat-input with its label floating to the left]

How can I achieve this?

Here's my `HTML`:

```
          <mat-form-field
            appearance="outline"
            class="ltr__mat-form-field"
          >
            <mat-label>مقدار</mat-label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="code"
              matInput
              required
            />
          </mat-form-field>
```

And this is my `CSS`:

```
.ltr__mat-form-field {
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper,
    .mat-form-field-wrapper {
      ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
        text-align: left;
        direction: ltr;

          ::placeholder {
            text-align: right;
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's how I finally did it:

`HTML`:

```
          <mat-form-field
            appearance="outline"
          >
            <mat-label>مقدار</mat-label>
            <input
              class="amount-input"
              type="text"
              name="code"
              matInput
              required
            />
          </mat-form-field>
```

`CSS`:

```
    .mat-form-field {
      input {
        &.amount-input.mat-input-element {
          text-align: left;
          direction: ltr;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: mat-form-field with correct floating label]

Answer (score 0):

Since angular material components generally do not respond to the CSS `direction` property properly, it would be better for you to use the `dir` HTML attribute instead. and add only the `text-align: left;` in the CSS file. (Though in this case, the direction works properly);
You can also ignore the class selector for `mat-form-field` as well.

[here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18857) you can learn more about angular material components issue with CSS `direction`

```css
mat-form-field {
  input {
    &.amount-input.mat-input-element {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>مقدار</mat-label>
  <input class="amount-input" type="text" name="code" matInput required dir='ltr'  />
</mat-form-field>
```