# Angular material input on arabic language not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-translate

In `ngx-translate`, when language is changed from English to Arabic, Angular Material input is showing like this:

[image: input with border leaving space for a left-side floating label while the label is actually on the right side of the input]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I think you have to manually change the CSS. Arabic reads from right to left.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455012/how-to-make-mat-label-float-to-the-right-rtl-language-when-input-value-is-ltr ?